# Minikube - /var/log/kubeproxy.log: No such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to find the kubeproxy logs on minikube, It doesn't seem they are located.

sudo cat: /var/log/kubeproxy.log: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pod logs are located in `/var/log/pods/`.
Run

```
$ minikube ssh

$ ls /var/log/pods/
default_dapi-test-pod_1566526c-1051-4102-a23b-13b73b1dd904
kube-system_coredns-5d4dd4b4db-7ttnf_59d7b01c-4d7d-40f9-8d6a-ac62b1fa018e
kube-system_coredns-5d4dd4b4db-n8d5t_6aa36b9a-6539-4ef2-b163-c7e713861fa2
kube-system_etcd-minikube_188c8af9ff66b5060895a385b1bb50c2
kube-system_kube-addon-manager-minikube_f7d3bd9bbbbdd48d97a3437e231fff24
kube-system_kube-apiserver-minikube_b15fea5ed20174140af5049ecdd1c59e
kube-system_kube-controller-manager-minikube_d8cdb4170ab1aac172022591866bd7eb
kube-system_kube-proxy-qc4xl_30a6100a-db70-42c1-bbd5-4a818379a004
kube-system_kube-scheduler-minikube_14ff2730e74c595cd255e47190f474fd
```

Comment: @thanks hoque, I see two files under "kube-proxy*" such as 0.log , 1.log. It seems they are daily rotated logs and so I should be checking looking "most recent" number . Please confirm ?

Comment: I think most recent number contains current. btw you can also check container log in `/var/log/containers` directory

Answer (score 4):

A more generic way (besides what [hoque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6027873/hoque) described) that you can use on any kubernetes cluster is to check the logs using kubectl.

```
kubectl logs kube-proxy-s8lcb -n kube-system
```

Using this solution allow you to check logs for any K8s cluster even if you don't have access to your nodes.